# Installation Symfony 4 with Api (Api Platform)

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

There are two docs, both the me the same:

- https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9N1nOYfAl4 (SensioLabs)

Run this

```
$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton api
$ cd api
$ composer req api
```

Edit env

```
.env
...
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/api
...
```

Add an Entity (Entity/Hello.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Hello
{
    /**
     * @var int The id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string A name
     *
     * @ORM\Column
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;

}
```

Update the database

```
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Use the Smyfony Server

```
$ composer req server
$ php bin/console server:run
```

But then in my Browser (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) this Standard-Exception appears:

```
ResourceNotFoundException NotFoundHttpException
HTTP 404 Not Found
No route found for "GET /"
```

Youtube Video and Api-Plattform Docs tells me, when I use api,
there should be an nice Api-Plattform page instead.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried several 
times and checked all docs I can find ...

Thank you Simon

Comment: Have you tried without `/` ?

Comment: Just `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: super fast ;) "http://127.0.0.1:8000" with Firefox, IE and Chrome, all there tells
me 'No route found for "GET /"' And when I copy the url, I is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" 
on Windows 10 Home ...

Comment: this testscript `<?php $html = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8000'); print($html);` returns also an 404 Error

Comment: Can you show your `Controller`?

Comment: there is no controller. for a normal website you need an controller with a Route('/') function. but this a special api, regarding the docs and video you only have to add an entity and then you have a basic api functionality. (?)

Comment: ;) ;) ;) ;) ;) ;) ;

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8080/api` ?

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/api` works :) thank you very much n3k!

Comment: Now I can see the Api Plattform test page. I try to make test POST. But in addition, I get an error 
`{
 ...
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\Hello\"",
  "trace": [
    {
   ....
      "file": "C:\\xampp7\\htdocs\\symfony\\api\\vendor\\api-platform\\core\\src\\Bridge\\Symfony\\Routing\\IriConverter.php",
....` Maybe a Double Slash Problem. I try to fix ;)

Comment: the solution is to set getters und setters for an entity. api plattform please update the docs ;)